# Visual Studio report service - Calculated field that equals a range of numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, calculated-field

I'm having some trouble with calculated fields in Visual Studio Report Service.

I have fields called Accounts and Net Postings.  I'm trying to create a calculated field that equals accounts with in a certain range of numbers, for example accounts from 1 to 5.  If revenue equals those accounts when I put it in a matrix I want Revenue to display and then when I drag the net postings in totals them up and places the correct number next to revenue.

I have most of it working, but when I put Revenue in the matrix, it returns two fields, `false` and `true`.  The `true` field has the correct information in it, but I'm not sure how to remove the `false` field and change `true` to the title `revenue`.  Is this possible?

My current calculated field is:

```
Revenue = Fields!Account.Value > 0 AND Fields!Account.Value < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **Filter** to the Matrix to exclude rows where *Revenue* is true, or set the **Row/Column Visibility** to only show if *Revenue* is `true`.

You can use an expression like `=IIf(Fields!Revenue.Value, "Revenue", Nothing)` to display the string *Revenue* based on the Calculated Field. You could do this at the Matrix level or add another Calculated Field to your DataSet.

Comment: For the filter, I tried using
**Expression** [Revenue]
**Operator** =
**Value** false
and it breaks the report.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you update your question with the error details? Is the expression type set to `Boolean`? Sometimes it helps to set the **Value** expression to `=true` instead of just putting a string value. I've found filters can be a bit flaky in some cases, unfortunately.